# Auto switch language to English when switching from an app to MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I have two languages on my system ie English and Russian. Often I have a need to jump into a chat and type stuff in Russian, when I switch back from the messenger app or any other for that matter to MacVim I want the system or MacVim itself to switch the current language to English by default. I have not been able to find a solution so here is my question, perhaps someone has already achieved this behaviour.

Comment: A possible (but not ideal) solution is `au WinEnter * !sudo languagesetup 1`. The command `sudo languagesetup 1` is recommended in [osxdaily](http://osxdaily.com/2016/06/29/change-system-language-mac-command-line/) to change the keyboard language on Mac systems. A problem with this solution is that it requires Vim to have at least two windows opened. Finally, this might work better on MacVim:  `au FocusGained * !sudo languagesetup 1`.

Comment: as a matter of fact this solution does work. however since it requires sudo privileges after gaining focus(before switching the language) it asks for the password, to enter which I have to switch the language manually anyway

Comment: I completely overlooked the password issue, hopefully someone else will post a real solution.